# MySQL IF() function to execute a block of code based on a specified condition

Tags: mysql

I tried to using the MySQL `IF() function` to execute a block of code based on a specified condition.

Return `"KO"` if the condition is `TRUE`, or `"OK"` if the condition is `FALSE`.

The following illustrates the syntax of the `IF() function`:

```
SELECT
id,
IF(DATEDIFF( Date_PEC, Date_Start ) > 30, "KO", "OK") DateDiff_1,
IF(DATEDIFF( Date_PEC, Data_Analysis ) > 45, "KO", "OK") DateDiff_2,
IF(DATEDIFF( Data_Analysis, Date_communication ) > 30, "KO", "OK") DateDiff_3,
IF(DATEDIFF( Date_communication, Date_of_issue ) > 30, "KO", "OK") DateDiff_4,
IF(DATEDIFF( Data_Analysis, Date_Archiving ) > 30, "KO", "OK") DateDiff_5,
IF(DATEDIFF( Date_of_issue, Date_Payment ) > 30, "KO", "OK") DateDiff_6 
FROM `dotable` 
WHERE
 id = 161016;

+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| id     | DateDiff_1 | DateDiff_2 | DateDiff_3 | DateDiff_4 | DateDiff_5 | DateDiff_6 |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 161016 | OK         | OK         | OK         | OK         | OK         | OK         |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)
```

I need:

1. If all conditions return OK I have to update, for id number 161016, the ALS column of my table with OK value.
2. If at least one returned value is KO I have to update, for id number 161016, the ALS column of my table with KO value.

The version of the mysql database is 8.0.12.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Update ALS column? Please add table definition. Also generally speaking storing a column which can be derived is not encouraged and have you considered a generated column?

Comment: @Akina I'm sorry. You have right, I have edit the question replacing IF statement with IF() function. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE dotable
SET als = CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF( Date_PEC, Date_Start ) > 30) 
                  + (DATEDIFF( Date_PEC, Data_Analysis ) > 45) 
                  + .. 
                  + (DATEDIFF( Date_of_issue, Date_Payment ) > 30)
                THEN 'KO'
                ELSE 'OK'
                END
WHERE id = 161016;
```

Single `(DATEDIFF( Date_PEC, Date_Start ) > 30)` returns 0 or 1 depends on the condition is FALSE or TRUE.

When all 6 values are zero then the sum is zero and it is treated as FALSE which causes `OK` assigning.

When at least one value is not zero then the sum is above zero and it is treated as TRUE which causes `KO` assigning.

If some date value is NULL (or the value is not a date and strict mode is disabled) then `OK` will be assigned.

PS. I'd prefer to use generated column for `als` column instead of explicitly updated one - in this case you'll simply select actual value always.